# Getting error "AMQ8101: WebSphere MQ error (10806228) has occurred" when trying to start the command server in MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm Getting error `AMQ8101: WebSphere MQ error (10806228) has occurred` when trying to start the command server in `MQ`.

The `MQ` version which we are using is `7.1.0.6` and the environment is `SunOS`.

Please need your suggestions.

Below is the FDC file created:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                             |
| WebSphere MQ First Failure Symptom Report                                   |
| =========================================                                   |
|                                                                             |
| Date/Time         :- Sun July 09 2017 15:15:37 MEST                         |
| UTC Time          :- 1499606137.840536                                      |
| UTC Time Offset   :- 120 (MET)                                              |
| Host Name         :- abcd                                             |
| Operating System  :- SunOS 5.10                                             |
| PIDS              :- 5724H7223                                              |
| LVLS              :- 7.1.0.6                                                |
| Product Long Name :- WebSphere MQ for Solaris (SPARC platform)              |
| Vendor            :- IBM                                                    |
| Installation Path :- /opt/mqm                                               |
| Installation Name :- Installation1    (1)                                   |
| Probe Id          :- ZT160001                                               |
| Application Name  :- MQM                                                    |
| Component         :- zusStartManager                                        |
| SCCS Info         :- lib/zu/amqzupt0.c, 1.54.1.2                            |
| Line Number       :- 1887                                                   |
| Build Date        :- Nov 14 2014                                            |
| CMVC level        :- p710-006-141112                                        |
| Build Type        :- IKAP - (Production)                                    |
| Effective UserID  :- 325 (mqm)                                              |
| Real UserID       :- 0 (root)                                               |
| ProjectID         :- 0                                                      |
| Program Name      :- strmqcsv                                               |
| Arguments         :- QM.XYZ.                                             |
| Addressing mode   :- 64-bit                                                 |
| LANG              :-                                                        |
| Process           :- 9398                                                   |
| Thread            :- 1                                                      |
| QueueManager      :- QM.XYZ                                             |
| UserApp           :- FALSE                                                  |
| ConnId(1) IPCC    :- 280898                                                 |
| ConnId(3) QM-P    :- 72653                                                  |
| Last HQC          :- 3.0.0-18240                                            |
| Last HSHMEMB      :- 1.0.0-4454576                                          |
| Major Errorcode   :- xecX_W_DAEMON_UNAVAILABLE                              |
| Minor Errorcode   :- OK                                                     |
| Probe Type        :- INCORROUT                                              |
| Probe Severity    :- 3                                                      |
| Probe Description :- AMQ6125: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred.  |
| FDCSequenceNumber :- 0                                                      |
| Arith1            :- 9495 (0x2517)                                          |
| Arith2            :- 50 (0x32)                                              |
| Comment1          :- Timed-out waiting for process manager to start.        |
|                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Are you able to share the messages from the server-side logs?

Comment: @Matt: I have provided the server side logs on my other comments, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start off by mentioning that IBM MQ v7.1 went out of support on April 30th 2017.  I would recommend that you move to a supported level of IBM MQ.  Keep in mind that IBM MQ v7.5 goes out of support on April 30th 2018.  Dates have not been announced for v8 or v9 yet, but IBM commits to at least 5 years of support which would give them support until at least June 2019 for v8 and June 2021 for v9.

---

The IBM MQ Technote "[Common WebSphere MQ messages and most likely causes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21265188#8101)
" indicates a FDC may be created in /var/mqm/errors when a AMQ8101 is returned.  If a FDC is created can you please edit your question and add the top portion of the FDC file?

---

If you run mqrc against that error code as a hex error code it comes back with the following:

```
$ mqrc 0x10806228

 276849192  0x10806228  xecX_W_DAEMON_UNAVAILABLE
```

IBM has stated to me in past PMRs that IBM MQ "... traditionally dumps out the hex value for return codes that it does not know about.  When this happens then it normally means we have hit an error path that we didn't expect and so we should try to fix this by adding a new message."

In APAR IT16270 they described a different unexpected error being returned as "a coding error resulted in an internal undocumented error code ... being returned to the application."

Based on this if it reproducible in a supported version of IBM MQ or if you have a extended support contract for v7.1 I would suggest opening a PMR with IBM to troubleshoot the issue.

---

**UPDATE 2017-07-10**

Based on the FDC indicating `Timed-out waiting for process manager to start` and further information from the OP that a restart of the queue manager solved the problem, I believe the `amqzmur0` process was hung and not responding, this is the "Restartable process manager". Restarting the queue manager would have restarted this process.

Comment: Hi Josh,Thank you for your inputs. I have pasted the top portion of FDC file(to view it best, click on edit). We have extended contract with IBM for MQ 7.1 till December 2017, so I can open a PMR. Can you please suggest how can I bring the command server to running status. Thank you.

Comment: @Rinak you can format things by highlighting them and selecting the `{}` icon above the editor, this puts the text into a code block.  You can do the same by adding four spaces to the start of each line.  I have done this on your question, you can click edit to see what it looks like.

Comment: @Rinak The FDC indicates `Timed-out waiting for process manager to start`.  Can you check to see if you have a process called `amqzmur0` running for that queue manager?  If you do not then look for a FDC related to that process ending.  Also what user are you running the strmqcsv comand as?

Comment: I'm executing all the commands as root user. I see a lots of amqzlaa0 process and one amqzmur0 process.

Comment: Try running the commands as `mqm`, the IBM MQ control commands should be run as the `mqm` user not `root`.  If that does not help then I would suggest you try and restart the queue manager.

Comment: :I restarted the queue manage and tried starting the command server and it worked with root only. As I understood there are lots of amqzlaa processes(It is the servant process that receives request from applications and responds back. In other words, it acts as the agent between the application and the queue manager resources.), which might be preventing the command server to start. Thank you for your valuable inputs.https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/an_introduction_to_websphere_mq_queue_manager_processes30?lang=en

Comment: I accept that     amqzmur0 might have caused this issue. It got restarted after qmgr restart. I don't see check mark to the right of the answer below the down arrow.

Comment: Corrected: I believe the amqzmur0 was hung and not responding, this is the "Restartable process manager". Restarting the queue manager would have restarted this process. The amqzlaa0 processes are normal and should not have caused any problem here. If my answer was helpful then please accept it by clicking the check mark to the **left** of the answer below the down arrow

Comment: Sorry but still I'm not able to see any check mark to the left of the answer below the down arrow, not sure why.

Comment: I do not find the check mark at the answer I want to check it. It is at the first answer which you provided. Please provide your email I'd so that I will send you the screenshots.

Comment: @Rinak the answer **is** already accepted as of yesterday, you can only accept one answer.  Comments are just part of the same answer.  Thank you for the accept!